# Swagger UI can't read referenced JSON

Tags: node.js, json, express, swagger, swagger-ui

So I am creating an API using express, cors and sequelizer. Now I want my API do have a decent documentation and found Swagger UI to be very useful for this.

To my issue: Since my database is not just one table and the routes are more complicated I wanted to separate the JSON into several files for a better overview. Now the reference I try to use in the `index.json` just doesn't work. It just seems like `info.json` won't even be touched.

Here you see my setup of Swagger UI at the beginnig of my node index file:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const db = require("./app/models");
const swaggerDocument = require("./app/swagger/index.json");
const swaggerUi = require("swagger-ui-express");

const swaggerOptions = {
    swaggerOptions: {
        validatorUrl: null
    }
};

app.use("/docs", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument, swaggerOptions));
```

`./app/swagger/index.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "$ref": "info.json"
    },
    "consumes": [
        "application/json"
    ],
    "produces": [
        "application/json"
    ]
}
```

and the referenced `info.json` being in the same folder as `index.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "title": "App",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "App API Documentation",
    "contact": {
        "name": "My Name",
        "url": "foo.bar"
    },
    "servers": [
        "http://localhost:8000"
    ]
}
```

In case it is useful: I run everything on docker-compose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `info` object does not support `$ref`. The content of the `info` object must be specified inline.

Also, OpenAPI 2.0 (`swagger: '2.0'`) does not support `servers`, it uses `host` + `basePath` + `schemes` instead. These keys must be in the root level of the spec. See [API Host and Base Path](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/api-host-and-base-path/).

```json
// ./app/swagger/index.json

{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "title": "App",
        "version": "0.1",
        "description": "App API Documentation",
        ...
    },

    "host": "localhost:8000",
    "schemes": ["http"],
    ...
}
```